# Spreadsheet Mark up Language

Tags: xml, xls, xlsx, odf

Is there a complete reference or documentation for **Spreadsheet Markup Language**? Which was used to create files in MS-Excel, Openoffice Calc etc, similar to XML?

Answer (score 2):

The [OfficeOpenXML format](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/TC45_current_work/TC45_available_docs.htm) used by Excel2007 and above for .xlsx files is detailed on the ECMA site.

The [SpreadsheetML format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28office.10%29.aspx) available as an option since Excel2003 is published by Microsoft.

The [Open Document Format](https://www.oasis-open.org/standards) used by OpenOffice Calc (OASIS)

For reference, the old MS BIFF formats (.xls for Excel) are [published online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313118%28v=office.12%29) by Microsoft